# Timestamp / date as key for cassandra column family / hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have to create and query a column family with composite key as [timestamp,long]. Also,
while querying I want to fire range query for timestamp (like timestamp between xxx and yyy) Is this possible ?

Currently I am doing something really funny (Which I know its not correct). I create keys with timestamp string for given range and concatenate with long.

```
like ,
1254345345435-1234
3423432423432-1234
1231231231231-9999
```

and pass set of keys to hector api. (so if i have date range for 1 month and I want every minute data, i create 30 * 24 * 60 * [number of secondary key - long])

I can solve concatenation issue with composite key. But query part is what I am trying to understand.

As far as I understood, As we are using RandomPartitioner we cannot really query based on range as keys are MD5 checksum. Whats ideal design for this kind of use case ?

my schema and requirements are as follows : (actual csh)

```
    CREATE TABLE report(
        ts timestamp,
        user_id long,
        svc1 long,
        svc2 long,
        svc3 long,
        PRIMARY KEY(ts, user_id));

select from report where ts between (123445345435 and 32423423424) and user_id is in (123,567,987)
```

Comment: You understand correctly - no rowkey range queries with random partitioner.

Comment: @tysonjh What is alternative for such case ? I think its quite common case...simple timeline chart.

Comment: you need to model your schema after how you plan to query it, so create a reverse (aka inverse, inverted) index on the values you wish to range query using a suitable granularity that allows you to query them at your desired precision.

Comment: I added an answer since any further explanation will be pretty involved

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do range queries on the first component of a composite key.  Instead, you should write a sentinel value such as a daystamp (the unix epoch at midnight on the current day) as the key, then write a composite column as timestamp:long.  This way you can provide the keys that comprise your range, and slice on the timestamp component of the composite column.

Answer (score 1):

Denormalize! You must model your schema in a manner that will enable the types of queries you wish to perform. We create a reverse (aka inverted, inverse) index for such scenarios.

```
CREATE TABLE report(
    KEY uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    svc1 bigint,
    svc2 bigint,
    svc3 bigint
);

CREATE TABLE ReportsByTime(
    KEY ascii PRIMARY KEY
) with default_validation=uuid AND comparator=uuid;

CREATE TABLE ReportsByUser(
    KEY bigint PRIMARY KEY
)with default_validation=uuid AND comparator=uuid;
```

See [here](http://www.royans.net/arch/cassandra-inverted-index/) for a nice explanation. What you are doing now is generating your own `ascii` key in the `times` table, to enable yourself to perform the range slice query you want - it doesn't have to be `ascii` though just something you can use to programmatically generate your own slice keys with.

You can use this approach to facilitate all of your queries, this likely isn't going to suit your application directly but the idea is the same.  You can squeeze more out of this by adding meaningful values to the column keys of each table above.

```
cqlsh:tester> select * from report;
 KEY                                  | svc1 | svc2 | svc3
--------------------------------------+------+------+------
 1381b530-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 |  332 |  333 |  334
 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 |  222 |  223 |  224
 13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 |  112 |  113 |  114


cqlsh:tester> select * from times;
 KEY,1212051037 | 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5,13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 | 1381b530-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5,1381b530-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5
 KEY,1212051035 | 13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5,13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 | 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5,13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5
 KEY,1212051036 | 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5,13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5

cqlsh:tester> select * from users;
 KEY         | 13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 | 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5
-------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 23123123231 | 13816710-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5 | 13818e20-1dd2-11b2-0000-242d50cf1fb5
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use wide rows, where Key is timestamp and Column Name as Long-Value then you can pass multiple key's (timestamp's) to getKeySlice and select multiple column's to withColumnSlice by there name (which is id).

As I don't know what is column name and value, I feel this can help you. Can you provide more details of your column family definition.

Comment: He wants to do range queries on timestamp, so this will not work.

Comment: @rs_atl As per my understanding I won't be able to fire range query as keys are md5...is it correct ? Or is there an alternative....simple scenario here is to show timeline chart. Is there a better way to design column family ? @ user1793389 so anyways I will have to pass all keys right ?

Comment: You are correct.  You can use ByteOrderedPartitioner to do range queries on keys, but this is a bad idea because the cluster will almost certainly become unbalanced.  The alternative is what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @rs_atl If he define a composite column he can create query ranges on 1st column but how can he fetch only columns with LonType In (v1, v2, v3)? **Can he pass list of values for 2nd component?**

**Jigar, rs_atl was asking you to create composite column's not composite keys.** 

My solution requires you to pass multiple keys to getKeySlice.