# Filter data on row key in Random Partitioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I'm working on Cassandra Hadoop integration (MapReduce). We have used `RandomPartitioner` to insert data to gain faster write speed. Now we have to read that data from Cassandra in MapReduce and perform some calculations on it.

From the lots of data we have in cassandra we want to fetch data only for particular row keys but we are unable to do it due to `RandomPartitioner` - there is an assertion in the code.

Can anyone please guide me how should I filter data based on row key on the Cassandra level itself (I know data is distributed across regions using hash of the row key)?

Would using secondary indexes (still trying to understand how they works) solve my problem or is there some other way around it?

I want to use cassandra MR to calculate some KPI's on the data which is stored in cassandra continuously. So here fetching whole data from cassandra every time seems an overhead to me? The rowkey I'm using is like "(timestamp/60000)_otherid"; this CF contains reference of rowkeys of actual data stored in other CF. so to calculate KPI I will work for a particular minute and fetch data from other CF, and process it.

Comment: Are you writing your own InputFormat or using Cassandra's?

Comment: @tysonjh I'm using the default InputFormat provided by Cassandra MR - ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java.

Comment: @All Let me share more details. I want to use cassandra MR to calculate some KPI's on the data which is stored in cassandra continuously. So here fetching whole data from cassandra every time seems an overhead to me? 

The rowkey I'm using is like "(timestamp/60000)_otherid"; this CF contains reference of rowkeys of actual data stored in other CF. so to calculate KPI I will work for a particular minute and fetch data from other CF, and process it.

Comment: I put your clarifications in the question.

Comment: @AyushV I don't see a problem here... You are already using a secondary index in your `timestamp/60000_otherid` column family to get data from the other CF. You will not be fetching all the data, just what is in the time-range you are interested in based on your index CF. Supposing you can generate this `otherid` at will, you can emulate a range slice already to create your MapR splits.

Comment: The only problem with that suggestion is that I presume `otherid` is some value that's not known at query time, otherwise there probably would be no issue.  So if you can eliminate `otherid` from the key and put it as a component in a composite column name, you'd have a known key (or keys) you'd be querying on each pass.

Comment: @rs_atl I know the key I have to search but the issue is RandomPartioner (RP) doesn't allow it and, at the same time, I cannot leave RP as well, as we need want the write throughput.

Comment: @tysonjh I'm confused - I'm looking at the cassandra hadoop API (ConfigHelper and SlicePredicate class) description and looking for the options. I don't see any way to fetch data from cassandra using the time bucket or other :(

Comment: You want to fetch by column range.  If your keys are just buckets, then the column names are what you care about.

Comment: @AyushV if the buckets (keys) are known as you suggest then the RP doesn't even come into play. Just generate your own splits (lists of keys), then query them directly. If you don't see the option for this in what Cassandra provides you will need to write it yourself (it's not too bad I promise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using RandomPartitioner, keys are *not sorted*, so you cannot do a range query on your keys to limit the data.  Secondary indexes work on columns not keys, so they won't help you either.  You have two options for filtering the data:

Choose a data model that allows you to specify a thrift `SlicePredicate`, which will give you a range of columns regardless of key, like this:

```
SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setSlice_range(new SliceRange(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(start), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(end), false, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(conf, predicate);
```

Or use your map stage to do this by simply ignoring input keys that are outside your desired range.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Acc to Cassandra API Wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API), SliceRange  could be thought of as Cassandra's version of LIMIT and ORDER BY. At the same time I cannot filter my data in Map, as it is BigData, which will increase continuosly over time. Hence, I don't think it will be a good approach.

It seems the only soln cassandra has is to switch from RandomPartioner to OrderPreserving one. I'm now trying to integrate Hector and Hadoop http://code.google.com/p/hector-hadoop-integration/source/detail?r=3

Comment: You don't want to use ByteOrderedPartitioner (new name for OPP), as it creates hotspots.  And I would argue that map is exactly what you want, precisely because you are dealing with so much data.  Hadoop is designed to read ALL your data on EVERY job, and in fact this is quite common.  It's the reason you run it in parallel with data locality.  Also, slice predicates are very useful with Hadoop if you have a data model that allows for range queries on columns.  Since such models are among the most common in Cassandra, this is a useful technique.

Comment: @rs_etl Though my search requirement meets the BOP, I have to use RandomPartioner due to high write performance (14000 TPS). 

Let me share more details. I want to use cassandra MR to calculate some KPI's on the data which is stored in cassandra continuously. So here fetching whole data from cassandra every time seems an overhead to me? 

The rowkey I'm using is like "(timestamp/60000)_otherid"; this CF contains reference of rowkeys of actual data stored in other CF. so to calculate KPI I will work for a particular minute and fetch data from other CF, and process it.

Comment: @AyushVatsyayan Why not use time buckets as your row keys, then you can use a composite column name so you can do range queries using a slice predicate.  Otherwise just do it in the map, as 14k TPS isn't really that much and Hadoop can certainly handle it.

Comment: My only problem is reading the same data again and again. For eg. at T1 I have data with key 1-10 (read and processed). At T2 I have data from 11-20 + T1 data of 1-10. So, if I read the data at T2 I will have to read all data i.e. 1-20, which ideally I shouldn't do. This is my concern and I see through this I'll be wasting a lot of computing power, which will go on decreasing over the time with increase in data.

Comment: Then use time bucket keys as previously suggested.  This will eliminate the duplicate work by allowing you to specify known key ranges in your slice predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the Cassandra Hadoop integration but trying to understand how to use the hash system to query the data yourself is likely the wrong way to go.

I would look at the Cassandra client you are using (Hector, Astynax, etc.) and ask how to query by row keys from that.

Querying by the row key is a very common operation in Cassandra.

Comment: The question is about how to do this with Hadoop, which doesn't make use of a high-level client at all.  Only thrift query predicates are supported.

Comment: @Sarge, Thanks for the reply. Yes, you are right, search by rowkey is very common, but it doesn't work with RandomPartitioner where data is scattered in the region based on the Hash of the key (to avoid Hot Spots). 
Cassandra's MR only support thrift. I'm trying work on the way for Hadoop and Hector integration http://code.google.com/p/hector-hadoop-integration/source/detail?r=3

Comment: Search by row key does work with RandomPartitioner - this is assuming you're looking for a single row key. Otherwise rs_atl's answer is good.

Comment: @Sarge yes I'm looking for single row key. Could you please help me how does rowkey search works with random partitioner.

Comment: He's talking about normal get-by-key queries with a high-level client, not Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially if you want to still use a RandomPartitioner and want the ability to do range slices you will need to create a reverse index (a.k.a. inverted index). I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700288/timestamp-date-as-key-for-cassandra-column-family-hector/13727713#13727713) that involved timestamps.

Having the ability to generate your rowkeys programmatically allows you to emulate a range slice on rowkeys. To do this you must write your own InputFormat class and generate your splits manually.

Comment: Seems this is one of the most oft-repeated bits of Cassandra advice!